# Initializing array and getting reference in one line

Tags: php

I want to initialize array(in my case it's multidimensional) and I want to retrieve reference to a separate variable so i could access it via that variable.

For example to achieve this im writing two lines

```
$multidimensional[$some_key] = array();
$item = &$multidimensional[$some_key];
```

This thing works just fine, but if I wanted to do this in one like I had tried:

```
$item = &$multidimensional[$some_key] = array(); // syntax error
```

**Question** is there a way to do this in single line?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$item = &($multidimensional[$some_key] = array());
```

?